# How to write a batch file to open applications and close them if they are already open

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I have already read how to write a .bat file in Windows 7 to open programs but what i want to do now is to have that same .bat to close them if they are already open.

Let's say i run the batch file to open these applications at once to save me some clicks, after i'm done with my work i want to close them without having to go to each one and close them individually. So i want to have the same batch file check if one or all the applications it executed are open to kill their processes like i would do in the Task Manager.

This is the code i'm using in the .bat file:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\RocketDock\RocketDock.exe"
start "" "C:\Users\user\Random Folder\Programs\RK_Launcher_04_Beta\RKLauncher.exe"
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to you batch scripting?  This would be much easier with Powershell or even VBScript...

Comment: I would if i had some actual coding knowledge, this is just some test i wanted to do to see if i could batch open and close programs easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `TASKLIST.EXE`, but I prefer [`PSLIST.EXE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682) to check if the process is running. If it's running, use `TASKKILL.EXE` to close it.

```
PSLIST RocketDock.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  START "" "C:\Program Files\RocketDock\RocketDock.exe"
) ELSE (
  TASKKILL /IM RocketDock.exe
)
```

I prefer `PSLIST.EXE` because it's simpler to check the result.

Comment: Yeah i already knew about that one but i need the batch file to only do one of the two things: if the apps aren't already open then execute them and if they're already open then taskkill them but without doing the "start" commands again, otherwise i would still end up with the programs running.

Comment: See if this question and answer help... http://superuser.com/questions/232703/taskkill-exe-dont-throw-an-error-if-the-process-is-not-running

Answer (score 0):

### You can use these simple commands as well

Taskkill /im RocketDock.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
Start "" "C:\Program Files\RocketDock\RocketDock.exe"
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).